# Matplotlib mpl.figure.Figure() fails, whereas fig,ax=plt.subplots() succeeds

Tags: python, matplotlib, matlab-figure

I want to create a matplotlib *Figure* without using pyplot using matplotlib 2.1.2.
This fails with an attribute error.

```
import matplotlib as mpl
fig = mpl.figure.Figure()
```

> AttributeError: module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'figure'

However, if there is an import of any backend, before the figure call, it succeeds.
Alternatively within Jupyter, if there is a `%matplotlib inline` or a `%matplotlib widget` it also succeeds.

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg as tkagg
fig = mpl.figure.Figure()
```

How can the import of a backend add a *figure* to matplotlib?
Is this the expected behaviour?

The pyplot interface does not seem to have such a dependency:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
```

always succeeds whether backend was imported or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a matter of getting the import straight.

```
import matplotlib.figure
fig = matplotlib.figure.Figure()
```

works as expected, i.e. make sure submodules are imported before using them.

Comment: So importing the back-end does not really have anything to do with it? Probably the back-end code imports the figure sub-module and thus makes it available? Is it a general rule that sub-modules always need to be imported explicitly before they can be used, or does this only apply to matplotlib and some libraries.

Comment: Correct. Any submodule is a module, and a module needs to be imported. Often though, the `__init__.py` of a package does such things for you, such that you may have seen cases where this isn't necessary. matplotlib's `__init__.py` does not do it for the `figure` submodule so you will need to do it yourself.

Comment: That is very helpful, thanks. In my own modules I always import the sub-modules in __init__ and I just assumed that's how all libraries do it. But your comment makes it clear.